# c# Dynamic behaving differently from one solution to another

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, dynamic, reference

I have a really weird problem.  The below code works fine if I create a new console app and put the code in but if i create a new console app in my solution and paste exactly the same code in I get a runtime binder exception that the dynamic does not contain a definition for hello.  The wierd things is in my existing solution the code never goes into TryGetMember().

This is really bugging me and the solution is too big to move into a new solution and I not convinced that will fix it.  In the console application that doesn't work all the reference are the same as in the one that does work.  the only difference being it is not in the solution.  The whole solution is acting the same way with dynamics - the funny thing is this was working but suddenly stop so i create this simple program to test the theory.

Edit: The application that doesn't work in the solution works fine if I don't attach the debugger i.e. Ctrl+F5.

Any ideas?

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary["hello"] = "world";
            dynamic d = new MyDynamicModel(dictionary);
            var a = d.hello;
        }

    }

    public class MyDynamicModel : DynamicObject
    {
        private IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
        public MyDynamicModel(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
        {
            Values = dict;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            return Values.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, check if values added to dictionary correctly in your code

Comment: it does work outside of the solution but just not in it? - importing the working project into the solution make it not work as well

Comment: Is DynamicObject the type you are using in the real code? The main time this happens is with accessibility of internal members...

Comment: yes it exactly the same just not call MyDynamicModel - i thought it was an internal problem that why I create this dynamic model that takes in  a dynamic (IDictionary) to expose those member to a assembly other than the one it was created in.  However, they are in the same assembly in the example and still not working!

Comment: Outside of visual studio (i.e. not debugging it) it works!

Comment: Are both solutions targetting .NET Framework 4 Client Profile?

Comment: This has "threading race bug" written all over it.  Running without a debugger changes timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have visual studio setup to break on thrown exceptions. Just using Dynamics will throw and handle more exceptions then you think when dealing with C# objects including dynamic objects. The C# binder always tries to do things like call the static version first etc, and then throws a RuntimeBindingException that it can't find the member, handles it, and tries again for the dynamic version.

Under `Debug > Exceptions` make sure the `Thrown` isn't checked on RuntimeBinderException or even just all CLR Exceptions.